# Defining a basis for a transformation matrix in the complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to show that $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $f(z) = \operatorname{Re}(z)$ is a linear transformation (easy) and give a matrix of transformation (easy)

I say its easy because I've done this many times and know how to do it, however...

I've never worked with complex numbers and linear algebra before, so it's not clear to me what the standard basis is (which I need for my matrix.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see the field of complex numbers $\Bbb C$ as a linear vector space **over** $\Bbb R$ *(and not over $\Bbb C$)* and $(1,i)$ its standard basis since we can write any $z\in \Bbb C$, on its algebraic form $z=a+bi$.

Comment: ;\perfect, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Don't you mean $(1,0)$ and $(0,i)$ (if the field is the reals)?

Comment: @Mike This is not necessary but yes if you consider that $\Bbb C$ is isomorphic with $\Bbb R^2$ so the basis in this case is $((1,0),(0,1))$

Comment: I'm afraid terrible at math thinks that your $(1,i)$ means a vector in $\mathbb{C}^2$, instead a couple of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Maybe you could avoid the confusion writing $\{ 1,i \}$ instead?

Comment: @a.r. The standard notation for writing a basis is $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ with parentheses and the context generally avoids any confusion.

Comment: @a.r. no worries, i understood that it's what Mike said :)